# How do I make an authenticated call to a protected resource in a RestController in my Spring boot unit test?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a `RestController` class that extends Springs `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. From my unit test I now would like to make an authenticated call to the `/info` method. My rest controller looks like the following:

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@RequestMapping("/info")
@ResponseBody
public String info(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("google") 
OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {
   // do some stuff
   return "ok";
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler("/");

   http.antMatcher("/**")
        .authorizeRequests(a -> a
                .antMatchers("/", "/error", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .exceptionHandling(e -> e
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
        )
        .csrf(c -> c
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        )
        .logout(l -> l
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
        )
        .oauth2Login(o -> o
                .failureHandler((request, response, exception) -> {
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("error.message", exception.getMessage());
                    handler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
                })
                .tokenEndpoint()
                    .accessTokenResponseClient(new MyCustomOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient())
                .and()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                    .userService(new MyCustomOAuth2UserService())
        );
}
```

In my unit test I would like to call the `/info` endpoint as an authorized user. I am not sure of how to do that. I have tried with:

```
@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

@WithMockUser("someUser")
@Test
public void testInfo() {
    var statusCode = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/info", String.class).getStatusCode();
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, statusCode);
}
```

Unfortunately I get a 401 response and not 200. So how can I make a call to that method as an authenticated user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MultiValueMap as shown below

```
@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

@Test
public void testOAuthAccessTokenIsReturned() {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> request = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String,String();
    request.set("username", USERNAME);
    request.set("password", password);
    request.set("grant_type", "password");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, Object> token = this.testRestTemplate.withBasicAuth(CLIENT_NAME, CLIENT_PASSWORD)
            .postForObject(SyntheticsConstants.OAUTH_ENDPOINT, request, Map.class);
    assertNotNull("Wrong response: " + token, token.get("access_token"));
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should mention that I use `athorization_code` as `grant_type` and not `password`. But I also tried to set the `grant_type` to `password` in my setup and rerun the unit test but I still got 403 forbidden.